# Quantum Harmonic Oscillator and Diagonalization

Tags: homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, linear-algebra

Suppose we want to find the eigenvalues and the eigenfunctions of the following 3D Hamiltonian:
$$H=\frac{p_x^2+p_x^2+p_y^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m \omega ^2(2x^2+2y^2+2xy+z^2)$$
Now: On my own, right now, I have no idea how to solve this problem. This Hamiltonian is not immediately *separable*, and I don't see any trick to make it so. I can of course see that this potential is really similar to an harmonic potential, and so our best bet is probably to try to separate this Hamiltonian into tre one-dimensional Hamiltonians in $x,y,z$. However I cannot see how to do this, the term $2xy$ is really bugging me.

I went to consult the resolution of this exercise in my lecture notes, and I found the following: we should write the potential in the following way:
$$\begin{pmatrix}x & y & z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}$$
and then **find the vectors that diagonalize the matrix**. Once we find the vectors then we can, apparently, use them to separate the Hamiltonian. **Problem is:** I don't get how any of this works. I never seen an Hamiltonian written so strangely like a scalar product between coordinates operators; and **I don't get the link** between diagonalizing this matrix and finding a separable form for our potential.. How does this method work? What is going on?

Comment: This is just a quadratic form, this has nothing to do with quantum mechanics per se, the same method applies when solving the same problem clasically. The potential is a quadratic form $\vec r \cdot A \vec r$, you can always diagonalize the matrix $A$ since the anti-symmetric part cancels (as can be easily seen by writing it in components, and symmetric real matrices can be diagonalized by a rotation. This gives you new coordinates $x', y', z'$. The momentum part looks the same in the new coordinates, since it is $\vec p \cdot \mathbf{1} \vec p$ and $\mathbf{1}$ is invariant unter rotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it so happens that you have chosen your coordinate in such a way that Hamiltonian looks horrible (that is not separable) but you can choose good coordinates to make you're hamiltonian look good (that is separable).

All you need to do is to look for such a coordinate. How are you gonna do it? You have to choose eigenvectors of the matrices you have written, as your basis and your Hamiltonian would be separable.

Now I'm not going to do the calculation but If you do so, You would find (I use the following)

$$\begin{pmatrix}X & Y & Z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}X \\ Y \\ Z\end{pmatrix}=X^2+Y^2+2Z^2$$
Now it's kind look solvable.